# Why Am I getting Module has no attribute error when adding "as"

Tags: python

I have a directory `module` where I have a python file `tools.py`

I need to import `tools.py` from the parent directory of `module`.

Everything works fine when I specify `import module.tools`.

However `import module.tools as tools` doesn't work. And I get an error : `Module module has no attribute tools`

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `as`, use `from module import tools`. This will import only `tools` from `module`.

```
from module import tools
```

If you want to rename tools into something shorter, you can do that later in the code.

```
t = tools
```

Comment: Yup, that too :D

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. Yes that seems simpler !

Comment: If it's helped you and you think it would help others too, you can check the checkmark to mark this as the correct answer. Continue the great work :D